How to i sum a column on the last roll of a table in PHP?
I would like to sum the column age as shown on the image below on my table but im not sure how to implement this. i know i would need to use select sum(age) from user but where do i put this?
total sum
I did the below:
if (isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2'])) {
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE signup_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['date1']."' AND '".$_POST['date2']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        
        $x = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $output = '<tr>
                            <td>'.++$x.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["signup_date"].'</td>
                        </tr>';

            echo $output;
        }


You have all the values on the PHP side, so you can calculate the sum in PHP.

You can explore these two options:
1.) Whilst looping through your result, you can decide to sum the values of the 'age' column and display the total age value at the end of your while loop
2.) Write another query on your signup_date table that uses the SUM() SQL function to sum up the age column
Here we go...
Option One:
$ageTotal = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $ageTotal += $row['age']; //adds each age value to the previous age
    $output = '<tr>
                   <td>'.++$x.'</td>
                   <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>              
                   <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>              
                   <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>           
                   <td>'.$row["signup_date"].'</td>               
               </tr>';
    echo $output;
}

/*
You can access the total age from the $ageTotal variable.
echo $ageTotal;

*/
Option Two:
$sqlAgeTotal = "SELECT SUM(age) AS ages FROM user WHERE signup_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['date1']."' AND '".$_POST['date2']."'";

$resultAgeTotal = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlAgeTotal);

$rowAgeTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultAgeTotal);

$ageTotal = $rowAgeTotal['ages'];

/*
You can access the total age from the $ageTotal variable.
echo $ageTotal;

*/

i think you want to ask that where in this code you should write the sum code of age column and you know it that how to write code for sum but facing issue with syntax that where you have to write that sum code in order to get it print just after all the rows of column age in front end, if it is then follow this answer
 $x = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        
        {//this loop will fetch all data from db 

            $output = '<tr>
                            <td>'.++$x.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["signup_date"].'</td>
                        </tr>';

            echo $output;

            //here is the closing of loop and after this loop closure code for printing the sum of age column is written.
        }

        $output = '<tr>
                            <td>'.hi'</td>
                            <td>'.hi.'</td>
                            <td>'.hi'</td>
                            <td>'.sum of age'</td>
                            <td>'.hi.'</td>
                        </tr>';

            echo $output;


you can run a separate query for get sum of age field. like this:
$sqlSum = "SELECT SUM(age) AS sum_age FROM user WHERE signup_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['date1']."' AND '".$_POST['date2']."'";
$resultSum = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSum);
$rowSum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSum);
$sum = $rowSum['sum_age'];

//here you can use the $sum variable value

And if you don't want to run a new query, change your code like this:
$sum = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sum += $row['age'];
    $output = '<tr>
                        <td>'.++$x.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["signup_date"].'</td>
               </tr>';

    echo $output;
}

//here you can use the $sum variable value

